# Keep every data entry per ID on JOINED tables, given one condition

Tags: sql

i recently asked a question on how to keep ids and the values for each column, GIVEN that code 'A' is documented.
For one table, this was possible using:

```
SELECT id, code, xlt
FROM tab t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab WHERE id = t1.id AND code = 'A')
```

But what about JOINED tables?

As an example, here are two JOINED tables:
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2pmpIY_6)

JOINED table:

```
id  code  xlt
1   A     23
1   B     78
1   C     98
1   D     12
2   A     34
2   B     65
2   C     97
3   C     99
3   D     45
```

I want:

```
id  code  xlt
1   A     23
1   B     78
1   C     98
1   D     12
2   A     34
2   B     65
2   C     97
```

Thanks in advance

PP

Comment: What's the purpose of joining tab1 to tab2, if tab2 contains all infos of tab1?

Comment: the second contains column xlt

Comment: exactly, why not using only the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like i said directly

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.code, t2.xlt
FROM tab AS t1
LEFT JOIN tab2 AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.code = t2.code
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab WHERE id = t1.id AND code = 'A');
```

| id | code | xlt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 23 |
| 1 | B | 78 |
| 1 | C | 98 |
| 1 | D | 12 |
| 2 | A | 34 |
| 2 | B | 65 |
| 2 | C | 97 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/akQm4X2a)

Comment: Thanks, but what was the CTE all about?

Comment: it demonstrates that the FROM clause with join behaves like a CTE because both create a temporary table, which itself behaves like your first question

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.code, t2.xlt
FROM tab AS t1
JOIN (select * from tab2 where code = 'A') t2
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

But it's unclear why you would want to. Exists seems clearer and most likely would be more efficient in terms of performance.